# How to fix “Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)” in PHP output string

Tags: php, xss, veracode

I have the following php code

```
<?php 
$Output = '<table><thead><tr>';
$Output .= '<th>Display</th></tr></thead><tbody>'; 
for ($k = 0; $k < count($ColumnsInSQL); $k++) { 
    $Output .= '<tr><td>'.$KS_ResultSet_level[$k][strtoupper(trim($ColumnsInSQL[$k]))].'</td></tr>';
}
$Output .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $Output;
?>
```

Recently I run the code in Veracode and I am getting issue with `"echo $Output;"`.

Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Comment: What issue are you getting?

Comment: In the veracode scan I am getting "Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)" issue

Comment: @Barmar, your answer works. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `htmlentities()` to encode special characters in the variable data.

```
$Output .= '<tr><td>'.htmlentities($KS_ResultSet_level[$k][strtoupper(trim($ColumnsInSQL[$k]))]).'</td></tr>';
```